# Review NON-public oriented APP on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I created an App on facebook to post things on a FanPage. Only I am going to use that App, but for some permissions (publish contents) I must review that App (or it won't work).

Should I just add random screenshots and descriptions or is there any specific way for this case?

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: No you don't need to get reviewed. Just take the app live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#roles

If your app is only used by admins/developers/testers of your app, then you won't go under Login Review.

> **My app is only used by a small number of people, who are all listed in the Role section of the App Dashboard - do I need to go through Login Review?**
>
> - No, it does not have to be reviewed. If your app is only used by a very limited number of people - for example, to use the Facebook for Wordpress plugin to publish to your profile - it's completely normal to list them all as having different roles in your app's dashboard. They can be listed as Admins, Developers or Testers
> - Some background on this: To enable you to develop and fully test your app, anyone listed in the Role section of your app's dashboard can be granted any permission necessary to test without review by Facebook. The purpose of Login Review is to protect the experiences of regular people who may interact with your app. Directly adding a small set of well-known people directly to your app is used for software development, testing and small application deployments.